# How to properly setup socket connection from AS3 air to nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, actionscript-3, flash, air

I found lot of samples in here, but very old posts using very old node and adobe air versions. I made simple node js server which is working properly - tested with web browser. Node JS is version 6.11.

```
var http = require('http');
var sockets = [];
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {});
server.listen(8080);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.set('transports', ['websocket','flashsocket']);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    });
    socket.on("data",function(d){
        console.log('data from flash: ',d);
    });
    socket.write(JSON.stringify({message:"blah blah"}));
});
```

My task is to connect it to AS3 Air application. Script looks something like this:

```
public class CustomSocket  extends Socket {

    public function CustomSocket(host:String = null, port:uint = 0) {
        super();
        configureListeners();
        if (host && port)  {
            super.connect(host, port);
        }
    }
    private function configureListeners():void {
        addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
        addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
    }
    ....
}
```

It is connecting to socket with no error, but neither sending or receiving data are working. Only connecting event is fired and that's it. ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA is never fired. Also, on connect I send some data to node, never received.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Instead of using `socket.io`, like for web pages, I had to use TCP socket connection on nodejs side. When I create script like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var net_server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('blah blah \n');
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {

    });
    socket.on('error', function(err) {});
});
net_server.listen(8000);
```

there is bi-directional communication which is working.